# How do I pass variables from a javascript function in a view to an action in the controller in ASP.NET Core

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have set up a Create action in my controller class -

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Post,YoutubeURL")] Announcement announcement)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            string currentUserId = _userManager.GetUserId(User);
            ApplicationUser currentUser = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault
                (x => x.Id == currentUserId);
            announcement.User = currentUser;

            //UserName is also set to allow for easier access of username from the index view
            string currentUserName = _userManager.GetUserName(User);
            announcement.UserName = currentUserName;

            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            announcement.Date = date;

            announcement.Views = 0;

            _context.Add(announcement);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(announcement);
    }
```

I am then getting the required data from the user in the view using this form

```
<form asp-action="Create" id="createForm">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Title" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control" id="titleText" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Title" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Post" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Post" class="form-control input-lg" id="postText" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Post" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="YoutubeURL" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="YoutubeURL" class="form-control input-lg" id="youtubeText" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Post" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
            <button type="button" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I now want to get the users geo location using this javascript function and also send that to "Create" -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = geoFindMe();

function geoFindMe() {
    var output = document.getElementById("coords");

    if (!navigator.geolocation) {
        output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
        return;
    }

    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

        output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';
    }

    function error() {
        output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
    }

    output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

Everything is working fine but I can't work out the last step, How do I send the latitude and longitude variables to the Create action in the controller so I am able to create the model with these variables included?

Comment: Did you research Ajax ?

Comment: Also your `Create` action doesn't even take latitude and longitude properties.

Comment: I hadn't added the long/lat properties yet as I first wanted to work out how to include the long/lat variables from the javascript function

Comment: I have not looked at ajax, would it be worthwhile researching for this problem?

Comment: You need to make a start on this though, Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service.

Comment: It depends on what you're after. As previously commented, `Ajax/XHR` is the typical way to go. Your code shows you have a `form` as well, so you _could_ "inject" the geo coordinates in the form via `Javascript` as well - so it's part of the standard (non AJAX) `POST`ed payload.

Comment: I think injecting the geo coordinates in to the form via javascript is closest to what I'm trying to achieve as ultimately they are just being stored in the model through the create action. How would I go about injecting the variables in to the form? This is the part I don't understand. Cheers.

Comment: I recommend you to read more about model binders (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2). They will help you understand the communication between View and Controllers using a Model.

Comment: I think you can _try_ that yourself. Your code above already shows how you're setting `innerHTML`, so learn about setting `input` `value`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking to do something similar my solution was as follows -

I created two new hidden form inputs for longitude and latitude -

```
            <input asp-for="longitude" type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg" id="longID" />
            <input asp-for="latitude" type="hidden" class="form-control input-lg" id="latID" />
```

I then created the following javascript function to populate the values of these two inputs when the page is loaded -

```
window.onload = getGeoLocation();
function getGeoLocation() {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(useLocation);
    }
};

function useLocation(position) {
    document.getElementById('longID').value = position.coords.longitude;
    document.getElementById('latID').value = position.coords.latitude;
};
```